# Android: How to add another view on top of a native activity

Tags: android, user-interface, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am new to NDK and I am writing a game using a 3D Engine -Ogre. I have something like this in the manifest pointing to my native lib:

```
 <activity
        android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
         <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of or .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="OgreAndroidTemplate" />
```

Then I start this activity by calling this from another java Activity:

```
Intent engineIntent = new Intent( _context, NativeActivity.class);
            startActivity(engineIntent);
```

However, I want some UI handling on top of my game (etc. menu buttons or advertisements ) , and want this to be handled at java side. Is there any way I can add another view or activity for this on top of my game?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the NDK, but if you were using normal Android XML layouts you could have a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout>
   <YourNdkView/>
   <LinearLayout>
      <!-- buttons etc -->
   </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but sorry, I don't have a normal android xml layouts as that is a purely native activity.

Answer (score 0):

Through include tag you can add another view on top of native activity as:

```
<include:layout="@layout/yourxml"/>
```

wherever you want to add view.

Comment: Sorry, but I am calling the .so directly, I do not have any base xml for my native activity to add an <include> tag. Mind asking do you know any other way I can call an additional view from c++?